# How to check the authorization token and its validity from middleware or a common place for APIs in next.js and next-auth.js?

Tags: next.js, authorization, middleware, next-auth

I'm working on a project where I need to implement authentication and authorization. Now I'm currently stuck in verifying API authorization from a commonplace instead of writing the common code for each API.

For example, I'm currently fetching some data like this:

```
import prisma from '@/lib/prisma';
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { verifyJwt } from '../../../lib/jwt';

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  const accessToken = request.headers.get("authorization")?.split(' ')[1];

  if (!accessToken || !verifyJwt(accessToken)) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      {
        message: "Unauthorized",
      },
      {
        status: 401,
      }
    );
  }

  try {
    const posts = await prisma.post.findMany();
    return NextResponse.json({ data: posts }, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error: any) {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: error.toString() }, { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

As you can see in the above code, before fetching some blog posts I need to check the authorization. So how can I write the following code for APIs from a commonplace?

```
const accessToken = request.headers.get("authorization")?.split(' ')[1];

if (!accessToken || !verifyJwt(accessToken)) {
  return NextResponse.json(
    {
      message: "Unauthorized",
    },
    {
      status: 401, // token not found
    }
  );
}
```

**next-auth.ts**

```
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const authConfig: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: 'credentials',
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith@email.com" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        if (!credentials
          || !credentials.email
          || !credentials.password
        ) {
          return null;
        }

        const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/auth/token", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            username: credentials?.email,
            password: credentials?.password,
          }),
        });

        const user = await res.json();

        if (user && user?.data) {
          return user.data;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // 7 days
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
    error: '/login',
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        return { ...token, ...user };
      }
      return token;
    },

    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (token) {
        session.user = token;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
}
```

**jwt.ts**

```
import jwt, { JwtPayload } from "jsonwebtoken";

const secretKey = process.env.JWT_SECRET || "";

interface SignOption {
  expiresIn?: string | number;
  issuer?: string;
}

const ACCESS_TOKEN_SIGN_OPTION = {
  expiresIn: "1h",
  issuer: 'abcsoftware',
};

const REFRESH_TOKEN_SIGN_OPTION = {
  expiresIn: "7d",
  issuer: 'abcsoftware',
};

export function signJwtAccessToken(
  payload: JwtPayload,
  options: SignOption = ACCESS_TOKEN_SIGN_OPTION
) {
  const token = jwt.sign(payload, secretKey, options);
  return token;
}


export function signJwtRefreshToken(
  payload: JwtPayload,
  options: SignOption = REFRESH_TOKEN_SIGN_OPTION
) {
  const token = jwt.sign(payload, secretKey, options);
  return token;
}

// Verify authorization
export function verifyJwt(token: string) {
  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, secretKey!);
    return decoded as JwtPayload;
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log(error);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Next version is

> 13.4.6

Next-Auth version is

> 4.22.1

and I'm using the **App Router** of Next.js

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To create a middleware that scrutinizes the authorization token and its relevance, you can implement a mutual authorization check for your APIs in Next.js and NextAuth.js. Here's how you can revise your code:

In your project directory, you can generate a distinct new file named apiMiddleware.ts (or any name).

Check the authorization token with middleware by defining a function in apiMiddleware.ts. Take a look at this implementation for reference:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { verifyJwt } from './jwt';

export function checkAuthorization(request: NextRequest, next: () => NextResponse) {
  const accessToken = request.headers.get("authorization")?.split(' ')[1];

  if (!accessToken || !verifyJwt(accessToken)) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      {
        message: "Unauthorized",
      },
      {
        status: 401,
      }
    );
  }

  return next();
}
```

Here's how you can switch things up in your API route file: utilize the checkAuthorization function from apiMiddleware.ts as the middleware for your API route.Check this code snippet: import the checkAuthorization function and integrate it into your existing code.

```
import prisma from '@/lib/prisma';
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { checkAuthorization } from './apiMiddleware';

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const posts = await prisma.post.findMany();
    return NextResponse.json({ data: posts }, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error: any) {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: error.toString() }, { status: 500 });
  }
}

// Apply the authorization middleware to the API route
export default function handler(request: NextRequest) {
  return checkAuthorization(request, () => GET(request));
}
```

According to your project structure, don't forget to update the import paths in the apiMiddleware.ts file.
Simply apply the middleware to each API route that requires authorization, and you can use this method to reuse the checkAuthorization middleware without copying the authorization code repeatedly.

I assume that the verifyJwt function in jwt.ts correctly verifies the JWT token and returns the decoded payload if token is valid.

Answer (score 1):

for server side authorization write [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/middleware)

> Use the file middleware.ts (or .js) in the root of your project to
> define Middleware. For example, at the same level as pages or app, or
> inside src if applicable.

since you are using `next-auth`, you can use `getToken` function

> Takes a NextAuth.js request (req) and returns either the NextAuth.js
> issued JWT's payload, or the raw JWT string. We look for the JWT in
> the either the cookies, or the Authorization header.

```
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";

async function middleware(req) {
    const pathname = req.nextUrl.pathname;

    const isAuth = await getToken({ req });
    // then you add your logic

}

// specify for which routes you want to run the above middleware

export const config = {
  matchter: ["/", "/dashboard/:path*"],
};
```